# Remote C++ Debugging with RSE

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

I'm stuck after step 3 in trying to setup remote cross-debugging with Eclipse/RSE:

1. Installed RSE 3.1 on Eclipse 3.5
2. Setup a SSH connection profile to my remote device
3. built binaries using a cross-compiler

Now I can't find the Eclipse option to transfer the binaries to my device and debug using gdb. Under Debug Configurations, I can't find find a "Remote CDT Launch" or " C/C++ Remote Application" referenced by other tutorials.

The only Debug Configuration options I see are the standard "C/C++ Application", "C/C++ Attach", "C/C++ PostMoterm", and "Launch Group".

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used the remote launch/debug facilities, but maybe these [slides](http://www.eclipsecon.org/2008/sub/attachments/Enabling_Remote_Development_with_CDT_and_PTP.pdf) from EclipseCon 2008 can help you.

The remote launch was AFAIK [moved](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg14499.html) into CDT itself for Galileo.

Here's the [FAQ entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#How_can_I_do_Remote_Debugging_with_CDT.3F) from RSE about remote debugging.